# Any way to create a method level breakpoint from code editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to create a method level breakpoint by selecting the target method in the code editor window and using a keyboard shortcut or menu command?

Comment: Please elaborate more..

Comment: @Chandrayya G K, what points need elaboration?

Comment: Do you want to know a keyboard shortcut for creating breakpoint?

Comment: @Aleksandr M, preferably. But other methods that don't involve lots of manual actions are ok too.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `B`.

Comment: @Aleksandr M, and how do I make it a method level breakpoint rather than line level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the shortcut for method breakpoint is not assigned in Eclipse, but you can bind it by yourself. Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Keys`. Type `breakpoint` in filter input, bind some keys combination to `Toggle Method Breakpoint`. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In eclipse select following view by going to `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Outline`.

After selecting outline it will open widget showing all methods and variables inside a class. Select only public method by clicking on hide non-public method option. (Green color circle). Then select all methods at once and right click for Method Breakpoint

Comment: This is not what I asked for.